# Visa or not visa in 2020 (type)

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

I am spanish and I have got a job offer in the UK as a tutor in a college starting in August 2020. It Is not permanent job.
Do I need visa to work there as a spanish tutor?
I don't live in England.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, during the "transition period" free movement still applies, so until the end of the year you can in-principle move to the UK and take a job without a visa. You can then apply under the EU settlement scheme to remain in the UK after the end of the transition period.

The big wildcard here though is the covid-19 situation. Right now face to face education in the UK is basically shut down and establishments are struggling to figure out how to teach remotely. People are being told not to travel unless it is essential. Frankly at this time noone knows how the situation will have developed by August.

Comment: The EU Settlement Scheme is probably not a viable option here, due to the residency duration requirements over the past 5 years.

Comment: My understanding is that as long as you arrive by the end of the transition period you can get "pre-settled" status. Then later if you remain in the UK you can upgrade to settled status.

Comment: @Moo Peter Green is correct.  The best course of action is to register for the settlement scheme to acquire "pre-settled" status.  Settled status is analogous to permanent residence under the free-movement directive (and the implementing regulations).  Pre-settled status is analogous to the "right of residence of more than three months" that currently automatically leads to a right of permanent residence after five years.